# Create a seperate cookie store for Chrome extension.

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I want to use 2 separate cookies for same URL in chrome browser, in which one I will use within Chrome Extension and one for normal tabs.

I am using API `chrome.cookies.set`. This API sets a cookie for a URL opened in all the tabs and also inside the Chrome extension.

Is there a way I can specify a separate cookie store for Chrome Extension ? `chrome.cookies.set` allows to specify a `storeId` but I am not sure how to create this storeId and in case if I set, would it use 2 different cookies ?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess you can inject a content script and set `document.cookie`?

Comment: You will need to use [webview](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview) inside an app for a separate cookiee store.

Comment: Have you find any solution??